# incompatible types: <anonymous TextWatcher> cannot be converted to Context

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make a "dynamic search"..

this fragment is where i implement the request... here i got an error (Error:(95, 40) error: incompatible types:  cannot be converted to Context) and MySingleton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(jsObjRequest); this is the line where i got the error

**Fragment:**

```
public class CercaFragment extends Fragment {

TextView textView;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cerca, parent, false);


    textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    EditText search = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.editText);

    search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {                // TODO Auto-generated method stub            }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {                
            textView.setText(s);

            String url = "http://api.geonames.org/searchJSON?q=londoz&maxRows=10&fuzzy=0.8&username=demo";

            JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
                    (Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {


                            GeonamesClass example = new Gson().fromJson(response.toString(),GeonamesClass.class);
                                                            textView.setText("Name"+example.getUsers().get(0).getName());
                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        }
                    });
            // Access the RequestQueue through your singleton class.

           MySingleton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(jsObjRequest);

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }

    });

    return v;

}
}
```

**MySingleton:**

```
public class MySingleton {
    private static MySingleton mInstance;
    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
    private ImageLoader mImageLoader;
    private static Context mCtx;

private MySingleton(Context context) {
    mCtx = context;
    mRequestQueue = getRequestQueue();

    mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(mRequestQueue,
            new ImageLoader.ImageCache() {
                private final LruCache<String, Bitmap>
                        cache = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(20);

                @Override
                public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
                    return cache.get(url);
                }

                @Override
                public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
                    cache.put(url, bitmap);
                }
            });
}

public static synchronized MySingleton getInstance(Context context) {
    if (mInstance == null) {
        mInstance = new MySingleton(context);
    }
    return mInstance;
}

public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
    if (mRequestQueue == null) {
        // getApplicationContext() is key, it keeps you from leaking the
        // Activity or BroadcastReceiver if someone passes one in.
        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mCtx.getApplicationContext());
    }
    return mRequestQueue;
}

public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
    getRequestQueue().add(req);
}

public ImageLoader getImageLoader() {
    return mImageLoader;
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do ***this***  within an event, you are not referring to the context of the application, but to the object that produces the event, to take the context in your singleton you must do the **MySingleton.Getinstance(this)...** outside the event, or instead If it's there inside where you want to call it do something like **MySingleton.Getinstance.(getActivity()) .......**

***getActivity()*:** is the method that is called within a fragment to call its  to context reference

I hope that helps
a greeting